# How to kill a cron parent workflow

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

Customer question: "I have a parent workflow that invokes a cron scheduled child workflow daily. If I want to stop the whole thing and re-start, seems that I just need to terminate the next "open" status child workflow (scheduled to run at next cron time)? "

Customer process: "I was trying to kill the parent workflow but it gave error msg "Workflow execution already completed"."

Answer (score 1):

Answers from the Uber-Cadence team:

Yes, terminating a cron workflow will also terminate the cron schedule

the parent workflow is already completed after it set up the cron schedule hence you cannot terminate a "completed" workflow

In the case of not terminating the cron workflow, it actually still exists between different runs but that run is block until the next schedule.